# How to display class's not inherited methods and fields

Tags: java, reflection

I would like to display on the console only methods of the class which were not inherited. If I wanted to display all of them I would just use:`object.getClass().getMethods();` but then I would get all of the method declared in the class and I would like to get only those which are genuinly declared in the class I am analyzing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method just for what you need: `getDeclaredMethods()`. It returns *all* declared methods, as opposed to `getMethods()`, which returns all *public* methods, whether inherited or not.

Answer (score 1):

The `Method` class has a `getDeclaringClass()` method which returns the class in which the method is declared. You can use it like so

```
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Method[] methods = Driver.class.getMethods();
        for (Method method : methods) {
            if (method.getDeclaringClass().equals(Driver.class)) {
                System.out.println(method);
            }           
        }
    }

    public void doSomething() {
    }
}
```

In other words, you check if the method is declared in the actual type you are interested in.

Or use what Marko suggested.